# Jquery "contains" multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, contains

I am finding all the divs in a document which contains inside a text: 'thetext' and i am changing this text:

```
$("div:contains('thetext'):not(:has(*))").each(function () {

  $(this).text($(this).text() + " anotherTextAddedBefore");

 })
```

Is it possible to put inside contains multiple values?
I would like to find the divs whic contains: 'thetext', but also another values, for example: 'thetext1', 'thetext2',etc

I`d want to make it in one procedure and not in more: dont want to use as many procedures as texts i´d like to find.

Thanks!

Comment: `$("div:contains('thetext'), div:contains('thetext1'), div:contains('thetext2')")` is possible

Comment: `$("div:contains('thetext'):contains('thetext1'):contains('thetext2')")`

Comment: Wouldn't that be an AND condition @A.Wolff?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Ya but that's how i understand question, i can be wrong  `I would like to find the divs whic contains: 'thetext', but also another values, for example: 'thetext1', 'thetext2',etc`

Comment: Ah, on re-reading I see what you're saying @A.Wolff

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the multiple selector as a or condition like

```
$("div:not(:has(*))").filter(":contains('thetext'), :contains('thetext2')").each(..)
```

Answer (score 15):

A selector like this provides an OR condition -

```
$("div:contains('thetext'), div:contains('thetext1'), div:contains('thetext2')")
```

A selector like this provides an AND condition -

```
$("div:contains('thetext'):contains('thetext1'):contains('thetext2')")
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/3a72h/

Answer (score 4):

You can have an array

```
var array = ['John', 'Martin'];


$(array).each(function () {

    $("div:contains(" + this + ")").css("text-decoration", "underline");

});
```

[**WORKING EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GR3va/)

Comment: Thanks Underscore!  It is short, simple and works nicely!

Answer (score 2):

Just adding one more point to above answers, if you want to select elements that dont have particular values then you can use

```
$("div:not(:contains('thetext'), :contains('thetext1'),:contains('thetext2'))")
```

works as `and` condition

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array and loop it:

```
var containsVals = ["text1","text2"];

for(var i=0;i<containsVals.length;i++){
    $("div:contains("+ containsVals[i] +"):not(:has(*))").each(function () {
      $(this).text($(this).text() + " anotherTextAddedBefore");
    });
}
```