# How Do You Use Multiple Words In Jquery Contains

Tags: jquery

Is it possible words in a jquery selector line. For example if i wanted to use yellow and blue could i just include it somehow by adding a colon or something or do i have to repeat the script over and over for each word.

```js
 <script>  
 
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("p:contains(yellow)").css(
  {"background-color":"lightblue",
   "color":"darkblue",
   "border":"1px inset dodgerblue",
   "border-radius":"10px",
   "padding":"3px 10px",
   "font-size":"18px",
   "font-family":"arial",
   "text-shadow":"1px 2px 3px blue"
  });
  });   
  
 </script>
```

The script that i am using above does not seem to allow this, perhaps i am approaching this all wrong, i have tried different seperators such as the comma, colon, semicolon.
what i am looking for is some like the snippet below.

```js
$("p:contains(yellow, blue, green)")
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jquery "contains" multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23248809/jquery-contains-multiple-values)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('p:contains("yellow"):contains("blue"):contains("green")').      // Both yellow AND blue AND green
$('p:contains("yellow"), p:contains("blue"), p:contains("green")').  // Either yellow OR blue or green
```

Comment: Hi all, sorry first solution does not work, the solution offered by Navnath is exactely the idea i had in my head when posing the question however what it does, is to ignore all the contains and only action the last one, meaning that only 'green' is executed.

Comment: So you want to apply css to  all paragraphs with yellow, blue, green text?